# os.environ KeyError with PyDev Eclipse, working fine in IDLE and when ran from command prompt

Tags: eclipse-plugin, pydev

I am trying to read the environment variables in my python code. However, it is not able to. Below is the code which I am running.

```
   #!/usr/bin/env python
   import os

   for key, value in os.environ.items(): print key,"\t", value

   print os.environ["DUMBOLIB"]
```

Error i got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/debpriyas/CAD/PythonWork/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.py", line 4, in <module>
    print os.environ["DUMBOLIB"]
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 23, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'DUMBOLIB'
```

When i look at for loop, it is clear that os.environ doesn't have any of the environment variables i defined in .bashrc. 
However, when I execute the same file from command line it works, and it even works in IDLE. I echoed the variable in command prompt and I do see the value. 
NOTE: I do have ~/.bash_profile as well where I call the .bashrc:

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi
```

OS: Mac Maverick 10.9,
IDE: Eclipse Juno Service Release 2,
PyDev 3.7.1.2

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here. Apologies if someone already asked this question.

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables are always inherited from the parent process, so, a workaround would be starting a shell (which will load your bashrc) and then start Eclipse from that bash session.

Another option would be defining the variables to be system wide (instead of defining in bashrc) or redefining them in the python interpreter configuration (inside of pydev).